# Convert JSONObject into String array

Tags: android, json

I'm receiving a JSONObject like this

```
{"tag":"value1", "tag":"value2", .............}
```

How do I make it into a String array of

```
["value1", "value2"]
```

Comment: key is same for all the values

Answer (score 1):

Create the Arraylist and get the string from the jsonobject and stored it in the arraylist.

Do like this

```
ArrayList tagarray=new ArrayList();
JSONObject jo=new JSONObject(jsonstring);
for(int i=0;i<jo.length();i++){
tagarray.add(jo.getString("tag"));

  }
```

Comment: Can you check the edit please. It's not actually (my mistake) "tag1", "tag2". It's all "tag", "tag".... How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("");
        Iterator<String> itr = obj.keys();
        int i=0;
        String[] values = new String[obj.length()];
        while(itr.hasNext()){
            values[i++] = obj.getString((String)itr.next());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If tags are going to be tag1, tag2 and so on...you can use a for loop,

```
string[i] = jsonObj.getString("tag"+i);
```

Or you can make a model class with datatype of String or ArrayList tag , eg.

```
class ModelClass{

ArrayList<String> tag; 

//getter setter here
}
```

And with that use Gson for JSON parsing and mapping the data,

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

modelClass= gson.fromJson(yourJson,ModelClass.class);
```

And your work is done. You have each value in the ArrayList tag.

This is more useful for parsing and mapping long and-or complex json strings.

https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

For Naming discrepancies(according to the variables in webservice), can use annotations like @SerializedName. (So no need to use Serializable)

Comment: I put tag1, tag2 by mistake. Everything comes like "tag"

Comment: even better, then use a for each loop and your work is easy :)

Answer (score 0):

Use following code.

```
ArrayList array=new ArrayList();
JSONObject jo=new JSONObject(jsonstring);
for(int i=0;i<jo.length();i++){
  array.add(jo.getString("tag"));
}
String[] Arr = new String[array.size()];
    Arr = array.toArray(Arr);
```

Or you have another option.

```
 JSONObject jo=new JSONObject(jsonstring);
    String[] array = new String[jo.length()];
    for(int i=0;i<jo.length();i++){
      array[i] = jo.getString("tag");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is super cool , lib called GSON , which is really helpfull for converting all type of JSON into its object .